# Cell value upon checked box copied into Userform Textbox

Tags: excel, textbox, userform, vba

I have several sheets of which house numerous checkboxes,of which when ticked, the value of cells next to the checkboxes will be copied into a textbox.Currently using ActiveX Textbox, below codes work just fine

```
Sub checkBoxHandler()
ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text & " " &  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

But now i would like to use Userform Textbox since it can float on the workbook. Modification to the codes such as below does not do the trick (the value of cells next to the ticked checkboxes are not copied into the Userform Textbox).

```
Sub ShowTextBox()
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & vbLf &   ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Does anybody know how to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar project. I think userform does not support that kind of method. so i did this:

i put activex textbox on each of the sheets and named it accordingly (Textbox1,Textbox2..), and set the Visibility property to False

i assign macro (below) to a shape to pass the value of activex textbox to the Userform on every sheet :

```
Sub hocmsummary()
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text & ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Text

End Sub
```

Remember to change the Textbox name accordingly.

Comment: sorry for late reply..managed to test it and very big thanks..this helps me a lot..